# It is bad practice to expose submodules on JS (import * from ...)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I found my former collegue comment like:

```
 // TODO: Get rid of it. Don't expose to other modules.
 export * from './search.actionTypes'
 export * from './models/ISearchState'
 export * from './models/ISearchFilters'
```

My question is:

It is bad practice to expose submodules on JS? Or maybe it is related to code style and depends on a community practice?

Comment: Well if you need them you're kinda gonna have to expose them...

Comment: Its of course down to personal preference.  But there are pros/cons.  Exposing nilly willy wont help with optimizing builds.  But used sparingly can help in making your app more flexible by been able to substitute modules more easy.

Comment: Expose the minimum possible, only what you absolutely need. I typically export a single, explicit function from each module, seems cleaner. `export SearchAction from './searchAction';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is bad practice to expose submodules on JS?

Absolutely not. Note that "reexporting" is different from "import than export". It just creates a reference of the exported name to the import, and leaves the way the modules are loaded up to the actual implementation.
That means, that if you use a bundler such as Webpack, it will "inline" the final import, so there is no difference wether you directly import from the original module or from the module that reexports it (except you are using a wildcard import, that will always be bad for treeshaking).

> Or maybe it is related to code style and depends on a community practice?

Splitting up larger functions / classes into different files keeps things clean, and through reexporting you can create a unified import for your package (i.e. reexport everything inside index.js, then you can `import {x, y} from "/module/";`). Wether to split up code into multiple files is your personal choice, there is no universal rule.

> "TODO: Get rid of it"

Your colleague has a better overview of the project, so he might see things that we don't. He probably has a good reason to write that comment, I would ask him for his exact reasoning (maybe the exports are never used, or should be kept private by purpose ...).

That said there is one downside of wildcard reexports: If you import, you won't know where the function imported came from. You should always prefer named exports.